# Check if Dictionary is inside Array of Dictionaries in Swift 3

Tags: arrays, swift, dictionary, contains

I have an array of dictionaries like this:

```
var suggestions = [["keyword": "apple", "identifier": "0"], ["keyword": "banana", "identifier": "1"], ["keyword": "carrot", "identifier": "2"]]
```

I would like to append the suggestions array and before I do that, I want to know if the dictionary already exists inside of my array to prevent duplicates. How can I do that in Swift 3?

I tried to use the `contains(where: ([String: String)])` function for Swift 3 but I can't seem to make it work.

**UPDATE:** The answer by Daniel Hall made it work. Here's the exact code for Swift 3:

```
let newDictionary = ["keyword": "celery", "identifier": "3"]
if !suggestions.contains(where: {$0 == newDictionary}) {
    suggestions.append(newDictionary)
}
```

Comment: When you get a moment, would you move the answer merged into the question into a self-answer? That's the preferred approach for answer material here. Thanks!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I think the solution is more straightforward than the other answers suggest.  Just use:

```
let newDictionary = ["keyword":"celery", "identifier": "3"]
if !suggestions.contains{ $0 == newDictionary } {
    suggestions.append(newDictionary)
}
```

This makes sure that your existing array of dictionaries does not contain the new dictionary you want to add before appending it.

Comment: Thanks @Daniel Hall! I'm surprised it looked this simple

Answer (score 2):

Instead of using dictionaries, you can create a struct representing your data types like.

```
internal struct Entry {
    let id: String
    let keyword: String
}

extension Entry: Equatable {
    static func == (lhs: Entry, rhs: Entry) -> Bool {
        return lhs.id == rhs.id && lhs.keyword == rhs.keyword
    }
}

let suggestions: [Entry] = [] //...
let newEntry = Entry(id: "3", keyword: "orange")


if suggestions.contains(newEntry) {
    // Do Something
} else {
    // Insert maybe?
}
```

If you prefer to just keep using dictionary, you can use `contains`

```
let newEntry = ["keyword": "orange", "identifier": "4"]
let containsEntry = suggestions.contains{ $0["identifier"] == newEntry["identifier"] }
if containsEntry {
    // Do something
} else {
    // Insert maybe?
}
```

I would go for the struct option .

Comment: Using a `struct` is the way to go here. Dictionaries should not be used to just to store a bunch of static fields. Better still would be to make `Entry` `Hashable` and make `suggestions` a `Set`.

Answer (score 1):

Another good and straightforward solution, a solid alternative to Daniel Hall's answer would be:

```
let contains = suggestions.map(){$0 == newDictionary}.contains(true)
if !contains{
    suggestions.append(newDictionary)
}
```

I posted this answer, because it doesn't use the `contains(where: ([String: String]) throws Bool)` function.

---

**Explanation:** Basically, `suggestions.map(){$0 == newDictionary}` creates a `[Bool]` which contains on each position a `Bool` value checking if on that position of the array lies `newDicitonary`. Then, `.contains(true)` checks if the newDictionary is on any position in the `suggestions` array.

Answer (score 0):

Should be as simple as

```
suggestions.contains(where:{$0.contains(where:{$0=="keyword" && $1=="carrot"})})
```

where you are checking for a "keyword":"carrot" key-value pair. The syntax is a bit cumbersome because you are looking for something inside something.

Note that the above is shorthand for the full query...

```
suggestions.contains(where:{ 
(dict: [String:String])->Bool in  dict.contains(where:{
  (key: String, value: String) -> Bool in (key=="keyword" && value=="carrot") 
  })
})
```

which may or may not appear simpler to you.